# one dropdown gets correct value but the other dropdown reverts to default

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two drop-down lists that get loaded and a default value from db - I do it in the Page Init event (did it in the page load too but changed to page init based on some research i did on this topic). then when I retrieve data from database for a particular item and setting a selected value of each drop down list, I see the correct value set in one of the drop downs but not the other. to be specific, ddlEcsrowService gets the correct value set from the BindListingDetails, while ddlListingType reverts back to the value set in BindListingTypesDdl. Any suggestions? thanks in advance. code is below:

======================
create.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEcsrowService" runat="server" Width="258px" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlListingType" runat="server"  Width="258px" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

====================
create.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindEscrowServicesDdl()
        BindListingTypesDdl()

        If (Not Request("lstId") Is Nothing) Then
            BindListingDetails(Request("lstId"))

        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Public Sub BindEscrowServicesDdl()
    Dim tmpDt = CType(Application("EscrowServices"), DataTable)
    ddlEcsrowService.DataTextField = "escrowservice"
    ddlEcsrowService.DataValueField = "escrowserviceid"
    ddlEcsrowService.DataSource = tmpDt
    ddlEcsrowService.DataBind()
    If tmpDt.Rows.Count Then
        For index As Integer = 0 To tmpDt.Rows.Count - 1
            If tmpDt(index)("escrowserviceid") = "2" Then
                ddlEcsrowService.Items(index).Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub BindListingTypesDdl()
    Dim tmpDt = CType(Application("ListingTypes"), DataTable)
    ddlListingType.DataTextField = "listingtype"
    ddlListingType.DataValueField = "listingtypeid"
    ddlListingType.DataSource = tmpDt
    ddlListingType.DataBind()
    If tmpDt.Rows.Count Then
        For index As Integer = 0 To tmpDt.Rows.Count - 1
            If tmpDt(index)("listingtypeid") = "1" Then
                ddlListingType.Items(index).Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub BindListingDetails(ByRef Id As String)
    Try
        Dim tmpdt As New DataTable()
        Dim param As New List(Of SPParameter)
        param.Add(New SPParameter("listingid", SqlDbType.BigInt, Request("lstId")))
        tmpdt = SPs.ExecSPTableType("pgetownerlistingdetails", param)

        If tmpdt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ddlEcsrowService.SelectedValue = tmpdt(0)("escrowserviceid")
            ddlListingType.SelectedValue = tmpdt(0)("listingtypeid")

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: It's good that you posted code, but could you only post the relevant portions?

Comment: You seriously expect people to read all that?  Please reduce it to **relevant** code

Comment: Which one has the correct value and which one does not?

Comment: sorry, i have edited to present the code for relevant portions only. thanks

Comment: ddlEcsrowService gets the correct value set from the BindListingDetails, while ddlListingType reverts back to the value set in BindListingTypesDdl

Comment: Can you set a dropdownlist like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. if I set the value using the code below, it works:

```
        ddlListingType.ClearSelection()
        For Each item1 In ddlListingType.Items
            If item1.value = tmpdt(0)("listingtypeid") Then
                item1.selected = True
            End If
        Next
```

thanks everyone for suggestions

UPDATE:
I figured out the reason for this working and for FindByValue not working: the reference data had this id column as char(2) but for the other drop-down that worked it was an int; so the database was returning "1 " and that is what was loaded into the drop-down. when listing details returned value it was in an int form and never matched the one inside the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I commented above - can you set a dropdownlist's selectedIndex like that?

In C# you have to do something like:

```
ListItem itemToSelect = ddl.Items.FindByValue(itemvalue);
if (!(itemtoSelect == null))
{
ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(itemToSelect);
}
```

Comment: for some reason FindByValue returns nothing even though the value is there; I checked the value by looping through the values of this drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the below pieces of code from your `BindListingTypesDdl()`

```
If tmpDt.Rows.Count Then
    For index As Integer = 0 To tmpDt.Rows.Count - 1
        If tmpDt(index)("listingtypeid") = "1" Then
             ddlListingType.Items(index).Selected = True
             Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

with the one below. First check if the value you are looking for is present in the dropdownlist and keep the corresponding index of the item selected by default.

```
If ddl.Items.FindByValue("1") IsNot Nothing Then
    ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByValue("1"))
End If
```

Comment: for some reason FindByValue returns nothing even though the value is there; I checked the value by looping through the values of this drop down